# Regex Twitter Username from different URLs in PHP

Tags: php, regex, url, twitter

I've researched on Regex, and am trying to find the one which extracts the Username from various Twitter Urls. I've come with this one, but fails in the last example, can anyone help me?

```
/(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(twitter.com\/)?([@])?(\/status\/[0-9]{0,})?([a-z0-9_-])/ig
```

Tests are:

```
@Username <= "Username"
twitter.com/username <= "username"
www.twitter.com/username <= "username"
http://twitter.com/username <= "username"
https://twitter.com/username/status/608085900145197053 <= "username3" (FAILED)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your life will be a lot easier splitting up the `@username` and `twitter.com/whatever` parsing into two separate regexes.

Comment: thanks for your comment, the thing is, i want the user to be able to Input whatever Twitter urls he wants into a form field, then extract only the Username and add it to a db... for the UX i want him to be able to input whatever twitter url he wants, even the @username thing.

Comment: That's fine, and irrelevant to my point. You can do it it in two separate regexes, which will make the regex much simpler to debug.

Comment: I frankly don't think you even need regex for this. You basically have two use cases - one where the username is after `@` and one where it is after `twitter.com/`.  Simple string manipulation can be used in both these cases to extract the username value.

Answer (score 0):

I've come with this solution:

```
/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:mobile\.)?(?:www\.)?(?:twitter.com\/)?(?:[@])?([a-z0-9_-])(?:\/status\/(?:[a-z0-9]{0,}))?(?:\?.(\=.)?(\&.)?)?/ig
```

it works for all this cases:

```html
@Username

twitter.com/username

www.twitter.com/username

http://www.twitter.com/username

http://twitter.com/username

https://twitter.com/username/status/608085900145197053

https://mobile.twitter.com/Us3rName?p=s

https://mobile.twitter.com/user_name1/status/608128181753671680?p=v
```

Answer (score 0):

A better working solution when you're searching in some text is:

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:mobile\.)?(?:www\.)?(?:twitter.com\/)(?:[@])?([A-Za-z0-9-_\.]+)(?:\/status\/(?:[a-z0-9]{0,}))?(?:\?.(?:\=.)?(?:\&.)?)?
```

The only matching group is the username itself and it's mandatory to have twitter.com/ in the url